# Save multiple selected data

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

With this code on my form I want to save the selected Cars (all its data - id and description):

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cars, new SelectList(Model.ListCars, "Description", "Description"), new { id = "myCars", multiple="multiple" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cars)
</div>
```

but when I check if `Model.IsValid`, it's set to **false** and in my view I got this message: **The value '*(selected)*' is invalid**.

Can anyone tell me why and how can I solve this?

**My viewModel:**

```
    public ICollection<Car> Cars;
    public ICollection<Car> ListCars; //it's populated somewhere
```

**My Car.cs:**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "all its data"?  what will be passed back to the controller from the dropdownlistfor is just the selected id

Comment: @MattBodily actually is passed the description (only) but I want it passes the description and the id of each selected car

Comment: should have said the selected value instead of id.  By default only the value will be returned.  It is possible to pass both parameters back but you would need to either build a custom helper or create a jquery array on your view with both parameters and pass that back

Comment: I gonna try to build a custom helper but so I have other problem: I want this new helper be a check list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a solution that doesn't consider a good practice, but at least it solved my problem. Basically my logic is as follows:

1. Use a plugin for the dropdown helper
2. Have somewhere a hidden div with all the selectable values ​​passed to the dropdown helper (id and description)
3. When there is a change in the selected dropdown through JS item, "select" in the hidden div desired values ​​by assigning them a specific name in order to be saved

Like this:

**1.** *Use a plugin for the dropdown helper:*

I used [this JS plugin](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) (v0.6) on my dropdowns, so I have this changes:

**My dropdown helper:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cars, new SelectList(Model.ListCars, "Description", "Description"), new { id = "myCars", @class = "isCheckList", multiple="multiple" })
```

**In my JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".isCheckList").dropdownchecklist({ firstItemChecksAll: true, width: 350 });
    });
```

**2.** *Have somewhere a hidden div with all the selectable values ​​passed to the dropdown helper (id and description):*

```
<div id="carsHidden" style="display:none">
        @foreach (Caritem in Model.ListCars)
        {
                <div id="@(item.Id)">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id, new { data_Name = "Id" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Description, new { data_Name = "Description" })
                </div>
        }
    </div>
```

**3.** *When there is a change in the selected dropdown through JS item, "select" in the hidden div desired values ​​by assigning them a specific name in order to be saved:*

For this, I add an event onchange to my dropdown helper and manager that selection:

```
$(".isCheckList").on("change", function (e, data) {
        var hiddenDivId = $(this).data("hiddendivid");
        var fieldName = $(this).data("fieldname");
        selectManagement($(this), data, hiddenDivId, fieldName);
    });

function selectManagement(e, data, hiddenDivId, fieldName) {

        $(e).children().each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr("value") == $(data).attr("value")) {
                if ($(this).attr("selected")) {

                        $("#" + hiddenDivId + " #" + $(this).attr("value")).addClass("IsSelected");

                    selectComponent(hiddenDivId, fieldName);
                }
                else {

                        $("#" + hiddenDivId + " #" + $(this).attr("value")).removeClass("IsSelected");

                    unselectComponent(hiddenDivId);
                    updateRowsIds(hiddenDivId, fieldName);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    function unselectComponent(hiddenDivId) {

        $("fieldset").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("div#" + hiddenDivId).exists()) {
                $("div#" + hiddenDivId).children().each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("IsSelected") == false) {
                        $(this).find("input").each(function () {
                            $(this).attr("name", null);
                            $(this).attr("id", null);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function selectComponent(hiddenDivId, fieldName) {

        $("fieldset").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("#" + hiddenDivId + " .IsSelected").exists()) {
                var index = 0;
                $("#" + hiddenDivId + " .IsSelected").each(function () {
                    $(this).children().each(function () {
                        if ($(this).is("input")) {
                            $(this).attr("name", fieldName + "[" + index + "]." + $(this).data("name"));
                            $(this).attr("id", fieldName + "_" + index + "_" + $(this).data("id"));
                        }
                    });
                    index++;
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function updateRowsIds(hiddenDivId, fieldName) {
        $("#" + hiddenDivId + " div.IsSelected").each(function (index) {

            $(this).find("input").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("name", fieldName + "[" + index + "]." + $(this).data("name"));

            });
        });
    }
```

So now, always I select a Car I will save its Description and ID